# How do I concatenate two Snoc lists?

Tags: list, haskell, algebraic-data-types

I have to construct a Snoc list, the reverse of Cons. I've done to add one element forward i don't know how to concatenate two lists. That's the situation now:

```
module Tsil where

data Tsil a = Lin
            | Snoc (Tsil a, a)
            deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)


empty :: Tsil a
empty = Lin

infixr 2 |: 
(|:) :: a -> Tsil a -> Tsil a
(|:) a t = Snoc (t, a)

infixr 5 |++
(|++) :: Tsil a -> Tsil a -> Tsil a 
(|++) a Lin = a
(|++) Lin a = a
```

Comment: ...you do realize that this is completely isomorphic to a regular list, right? Just because you reversed the names of the constructors and the order of the `Snoc` arguments doesn't make it a different data type. If this is an exercise of some sort, are you sure you're understanding it correctly? In my experience, datatypes with a "`snoc`" operation typically support efficient access to the element at the opposite end of the list—which your type won't.

Comment: Why does `Snoc` use a tuple instead of just `Snoc (Tsil a) a`?

Comment: @pat the homework tag is obsolete now.

Comment: @LuisCasillas The fact that `List` and `Tsil` are isomorphic doesn’t make the answer completely trivial. (There are at least two “obvious” isomorphisms – the order-preserving one and the order-inverting one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list type is the same as Haskell's, so just make it a Haskell list, concatenate, convert back. Hooray for reusability in Haskell ;-)

```
toList Lin = []
toList (Snoc (xs, x)) = x : toList xs

toTsil [] = Lin
toTsil (x:xs) = Snoc (toTsil xs, x)

a (|++) b = toTsil $ toList a ++ toList b
```

Comment: The infix `(|++)` looks a bit borked syntactically. More importantly, I think this actually produces the wrong result: `(Snoc (Snoc Lin "a") "b") |++ (Snoc (Snoc Lin "c") "d")` evaluates to `Snoc (Snoc (Snoc (Snoc Lin "c") "d") "a") "b"`, rather than `Snoc (Snoc (Snoc (Snoc Lin "a") "b") "c") "d"`. I feel like that’s wrong, although I don’t have a good argument.

Comment: `a |++ b = fromList (flip (++) (toList a) (toList b))` would work.

Answer (score 2):

```
(|++) l (Snoc (t,x)) = Snoc (l |++ t,x)
```

Comment: This looks like the correct answer to me (I’ve added the missing `Lin` equation).